# Cannot mkdir folder in Android

Tags: android, camera, directory, photo, mkdir

I am having problem to running function Mkdir(). What should I do?
I already added read/write permission:

```
 <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Below is my code snippet:

```
private File getTempFile(Context context)
    {

        File path;
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){

            path=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Tanker/Foto/");
        }
        else {
            path=context.getCacheDir();
        }
        String pictureFileName = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg";
        if (!path.exists())
        {
            path.mkdir();
        }
        return new File(path, pictureFileName);
    }
```

please help.

Comment: try this `path.mkdirs();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 path=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Tanker/Foto/");
```

`mkdir` will not create the complete path. You have to use `mkdirs` for that

From the documentation

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any
>   necessary but nonexistent parent directories.

e.g.

```
    if (!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdirs();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creates the directory named by this file, assuming its parents exist. Use mkdirs() if you also want to create missing parents.

Note that this method does not throw IOException on failure. Callers must check the return value. Note also that this method returns false if the directory already existed. If you want to know whether the directory exists on return, either use (f.mkdir() || f.isDirectory()) or simply ignore the return value from this method and simply call isDirectory().
Returns

```
true if the directory was created, false on failure or if the directory already existed.
```

**check the return valu**e than you get proper reason for problem.